# Azir Passive Attackspeed bonus maxed at 80%

Tags: league-of-legends

Is Azir's Attackspeed bonus from his passive maxed at 80%?

He gains 2% Attackspeed for every 1% Cooldown reduction.
That being said, can you get more than 80% Attackspeed by having more than 40% CDR (even though obviously it would still be capped at 40%)

Comment: Is he even out on PBE yet?
Ill go test it if it is, if not I dont want to spend an hour patching to find out hes not.

That being said, I highly doubt it. But I cant say for sure

Comment: Well, I was just watching some Pawnce YouTube videos of him.

Comment: Ill see what I can find out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm that his AS bonus is capped at 80%. I bought 40% worth of CDR and had 0.92 AS; after buying another Forbidden Idol, my AS stayed at 0.92.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware, but you didn't have two Forbidden Idols in your inventory did you? Because the 10% CDR on those is a UNIQUE passive.

Comment: @Shelby115 No, I had Morellonomicon + masteries + Ionian

Comment: Okay just checking, I was grasping at that little bit of hope lol.

Answer (score -2):

It seems pretty clear as it is: it scales with your cooldown reduction. You can't have more than 40% CDR. So you can't have more than 80% bonus AS from Azir's passive. No trick or trap here :p

Comment: 1. This adds nothing new to the post. 2. Right, I was hoping his passive was calculated before the cap was applied and Schism verified that it doesn't.

Comment: It adds the fact that you just have to read the passive, not overthink it.

Comment: That's what the first answer says, hence the "nothing new". Adding that minor fact is more comment worthy.